# php Codeception not-so-quick start: [PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Undefined index: ELEMENT

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, codeception

So, I followed the Codeception [Quick Start instructions](http://codeception.com/quickstart) faithfully. I run the first example test using the PhpBrowser...

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration
#
# [further comments omitted]
# 
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://office.localhost/'
            browser: 'firefox'
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

and the test:

```
<?php

class FirstCest
{               
    public function frontpageWorks(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->see('We hope you enjoy it');

    }
}
```

and all is well.

Then I change the configuration to this:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://office.localhost/'
            browser: 'firefox'
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

per the instructions, and I have Selenium installed and up and running, and away we go...

```
1) FirstCest: Frontpage works
 Test  tests/acceptance/FirstCest.php:frontpageWorks

  [PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Undefined index: ELEMENT  


Scenario Steps:

 2. $I->see("InterpretersOffice") at tests/acceptance/FirstCest.php:22
 1. $I->amOnPage("/") at tests/acceptance/FirstCest.php:21

#1  /opt/www/court-interpreters-office/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:198
#2  Codeception\Module\WebDriver->see
#3  /opt/www/court-interpreters-office/tests/_support/_generated/AcceptanceTesterActions.php:363
#4  /opt/www/court-interpreters-office/tests/acceptance/FirstCest.php:22
#5  FirstCest->frontpageWorks
```

Selenium is driving Firefox, the page is loaded, the content that `$I` want to `see()` is there, so that ain't the problem. I have poked around in the source a bit, but haven't figured this out. I have tried changing `$I->see()` to `$I->seeInSource()` and found that does work, FWIW.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like current version of Firefox is incompatible with facebook/webdriver because facebook/webdriver hasn't implemented the new protocol yet.

Comment: Error you got is directly caused by insufficient error handling in facebook/webdriver code: https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/1.4.1/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php#L198 You are welcome to do some debugging and see what is actually happening there.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/468

Comment: Simple things first. Just use Chrome instead of Firefox.

Comment: http://phptest.club/t/does-anyone-set-up-selenium-3-and-codeception/1606/6 seems to suggest that "just use Chrome instead of Firefox" is the only available solution at the moment. FYI I did do some debugging, examined what was happening at https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/1.4.1/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php#L178, and -- no surprise --index  'ELEMENT' is indeed undefined.

Comment: Too bad the Codeception docs don't warn us about this and save us a couple hours of torment :-)

Comment: It is open source, you can do a pull request.

Comment: I've considered that.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is apparently that Facebook's php-webdriver isn't compatible with current Firefox.

[These](http://phptest.club/t/does-anyone-set-up-selenium-3-and-codeception/1606/6) [threads](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/469) discuss the issue in more detail, and [php-webdriver issue #469](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/469) tracks adding full W3C WebDriver support (which will fix the incompatibility).

A workaround is to add the `-enablePassthrough false` argument when launching Selenium. For example:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -enablePassThrough false
```

Unfortunately, [Selenium removed support for pass through mode in 3.9](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG), so you'll have to use an older version.

Another workaround is to switch to Chrome.

Comment: I tried this: 
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -enablePassThrough false`
and got [this error](https://pastebin.com/c2zAET5W). Any other alternatives?

Comment: @Shad - Unfortunately, it looks like `-enablePassThrough` was removed in Selenium 3.9. See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only solution was:

```
Install chromedriver in a path that is in $PATH (/usr/bin or /bin)
```

and using in your test class:

```
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()
```

It works with executing Selenium standard way:

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different situations on my Ubuntu ver. 18.x:

1. The vendor files has been for years, I have to rm the vendor fold and rebuild it with `php composer.phar require facebook/webdriver` for my PHP library.
2. The version of selenium-server-standalone-x.jar and chromedriver doesn't match. So download more version and try, finally you will get one pair to work.